# translating a headline, て form

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

TDL舞台に誘拐ミステリー⁉︎／噂、デマが飛び交って大騒ぎ

This is a headline from an article. How would you translate the whole headline? I don't know how I should translate the て from of the verb 飛び交う.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kidnap Mystery on TDL Stage! Rumours and False Stories Run Rampant: Massive Confusion

Literally "Rumours and deliberate falsehoods run rampant/fly around and [there is] massive confusion". The verb following  大騒ぎ is omitted to save space - standard practice in newspapers.